# How to open a copy of a Android project with a different name?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a newbie in Android development and so in Android Studio and I made a very basic project of a calculator and I want to modify this same project. So I have the original project named "Calculator" and the copy named "Calculator2". But when I run the project I get this message:

[image]

This is very complicated to me because in another APIs I just click in import for example and I have the same project with a different name. But in Android seems to be a bit more different.

Comment: Was the namespace changed also?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click in Ok I just get this in my console: Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565))
Error while Installing APKs

Comment: @gustavogbc I don't think so how do I change this? In manifest? Wich line specifically?

Comment: @Jarwin. You would have to change the packagename of the whole project. Shobhit's answer below gives you the steps to follow through. Michael Kemp's solution works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two different projects, but you never changed the name.  Your phone still thinks it's the same app.  It's only telling you that you need to uninstall the app from Calculator to install the app ran from Calculator2.  Pressing OK should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling the app on your device and then running the app from Android Studio. This usually works for me when I get that message.

Answer (score 2):

The steps are:
Just make a copy (using a file manager) of the entire module folder and give it a new name. Now open it up and use **Refactor -> Rename** (right click on the item you want to rename) to rename your module and package.

When you make name changes you have to make sure you change the name in `AndroidManifest.xml` and the `build.gradle` file.

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` make sure the package name is correct to what you're changing it to.

In `build.gradle` it's the `applicationId` that needs to be updated to the new package name as well. This will sync your files to the new name instead of still being tied to your old files.